# How to deploy separate 2 apps with 1 shared module on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, sbt

The application I want to run on Heroku consists of 3 items:

- a HTML frontend (*www.myapp.com*)
- a JSON API (*api.myapp.com*)
- and a common utility class both *share*

Since I use different subdomains (and I can't merge the 2 frontends), I have to create 2 separate Heroku apps, so I also need 2 Procfiles. Right?

**Now, how do I tell Heroku which Procfile to use?** (assuming everything is in one repository)

PS: I'm using Scala, Play and sbt.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I considered using branches or submodules, but it was too difficult to use my tools (IntelliJ, Jenkins) with this. So I created 2 jobs in my CI Server; each checks out the repository, adds the according Procfile and pushes it to heroku:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "#### Checkout repository"
git clone -o -f git@github.com:myself/myrepo.git $WORKSPACE/source
cd source/

echo "#### create Procfile"
echo "web: apps/app-api/target/start -api.port=\$PORT" > Procfile
git add Procfile

echo "#### commit locally"
git commit -a -m "prepared for Heroku deployment"

echo "#### push to heroku"
git remote add repo-heroku git@heroku.com:myapp.git
git push --force repo-heroku master && exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

If your HTML frontend is just static files then you should actually put it on a CDN instead of Heroku.  If you really want to run both on Heroku then create a git branch for each app on Heroku and then push associated branch to the right git remote.  If you have a git remote for the www app called "heroku-www" and a git branch called "www" then you can push it to the master branch on Heroku with:

```
git push heroku-www www:master
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Not just static files, I'm using the play framework. When using 2 branches, where do I put the utility modules? I looked at submodules, but it looked overly complex...

Comment: Are you referring to local repo dependencies?

Comment: nevermind, I ended up using my Jenkins CI server to generate a Procfile for each app in the local repository and just push it from there